# ios: differentiate between a programmatic call Missed and Refused to answer

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I need to make an iphone app which dials a cell number programatically and when not answered dials another number. I used core telephony framework to know the call states if dialed or connected. But i get the call state as disconnected in both the cases: if the call is unanswered by the callee and if he refuses to answer by disconnecting. Is there a way to differentiate if the call by my app has been disconnected by the callee or has been automatically disconnected due to not answering?
Here is my code

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
{
    if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)
    { 
        NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");            
    }
    else if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
    }
    else if(call.callState == CTCallStateDialing)
    {
        NSLog(@"Call is dialing");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"None of the conditions");
    }

};
```

I would appreciate any ideas or solutions for my issue.

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: In fact if the call by my app has been automatically disconnected, then i need to proceed to dial the second number else if the party has refused to answer i need not make the second call. This is why i need to differentiate.

Comment: I don't think there's a good reliable way to do that.

Comment: Okay.... Thank you so much for your help!
+1 for your answer!